# Пунктуация при "прежде" с глаголами

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая перед "прежде" в данном предложении: "Ты должна хорошенько подумать прежде чем решиться"?

Answer (score 1):

Ответ исправлен.

*Ты должна хорошенько подУмать, **прежде чем** решИться.*

Запятая ставится перед составным союзом ПРЕЖДЕ ЧЕМ.

В некоторых случаях союз ПРЕЖДЕ  ЧЕМ **может расчленяться**.

В данном случае ПРЕЖДЕ  ЧЕМ не расчленяется запятой, что легко **определяется по слуху.** Союз относится к однородным сказуемым, которые выделяются логическим ударением, поэтому **на слово *прежде* ударение не падает**, соответственно пауза после него отсутствует.

http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?id=58_628&layout=item

Пример с расчленением союза:

*Воротник поблагодарил и радостно согласился прЕжде, чем Олечка успела сообразить, в чём дело.* Н. Тэффи.

Comment: Вряд ли сказуемые однородные. Вопрос можно задать от одного к другому (*до каких пор?*). При настоящих однородных сказуемых такого не наблюдается. Первый глагол стоит в форме инфинитива от слова "должна", но оно никак не относится к второму глаголу - он независимый, согласования с подлежащим "ты" не наблюдается. Поменяем местами - при перестановке не должно возникнуть дополнительных знаков: *Ты, прежде чем решиться, должна хорошенько подумать.* Но требуется ещё запятая. Все признаки придаточного.

Comment: А я и не пытаюсь что-то доказывать на 100%. Это же не математика и не научная работа. Всего лишь пару аргументов в защиту моей позиции. Здесь же нельзя отвечать через "просто потому что". А смысл в том, чтобы правильно писать. Мне другого не надо. Почти не занимаюсь классификациями и терминологией. Это больше нужно учёным, а не пользователям языка. Союз фиксируется как временной, и его можно заменить на "перед тем как". Не зря мне изначально захотелось задать вопрос "когда?". Подчинительный, так как без главной части остаётся ерунда. Вся загвоздка в согласовании (с подлежащим), которого нет.

Comment: Если предложение началось в скобках, то и точку нужно ставить внутри скобок. "*А может быть, временной союз вообще к однородным сказуемым не может относиться*" — хороший вопрос. Думал над этим. Это смотря под каким углом посмотреть. Решил бы логическим ударением: *Когда позвонишь? Я позвоню прежде чем вЫеду.* — предложение структурно единое, паузы нет, ну и запятую ставить не хочется, тогда и придаточного нет. А с двумя ударениями пусть учёные классифицируют. Ну или автор: пропущено второе подлежащее или нет.

Comment: Еще раз перечитала ваши длинные рассуждения, которые  вы выдаете за доказательства. Ничего это будет не нужно, если вы коротко и ясно обозначите грамматику. Несколько коротких слов, и вашу позицию уже вряд ли кто оспорит.

Comment: Самым весомым доказательством считаю отсутствие согласования с подлежащим. "Вы никогда не научитесь грамотно писать" — а я уже умею))) "если вы коротко и ясно обозначите грамматику" — это про члены предложения? Я эту тему не люблю, она мне с пунктуацией никогда не помогала.

Comment: У вас получилось интересное предложение: *Ничего это(го) будет не нужно.* Точно правильно так: *Ничего этого не будет нужно.* Существует ли ваш вариант двойного отрицания (без отрицания глагола - оно в какой-то мере звучит)? Если да, то где можно почитать об этом?

Comment: Я так и понял. Сравниваю именно при слове "ничего": *ничего будет не нужно* и *ничего не будет нужно*. Но смущает первый вариант. Он не равен "*это будет не нужно*" - совсем разные вещи, здесь "это" не в подчинении. Не могу придумать похожих примеров без отрицания глагола.

Answer (score 1):

Запятая нужна. Составной союз "прежде чем" требует постановки знаков препинания.

*Ты должна хорошенько подУмать, (до каких пор?) прежде чем решИться.* || После запятой идёт уточнение.

Решается оно так: опускаем вторую часть и смотрим, куда относится союз:
*Ты должна хорошенько подумать прежде.* || "Прежде" как лишнее. Его незачем акцентировать. Значит, перед ним нужна запятая.
*Ты должна хорошенько подумать.* || Нормально.

Но этот союз может расчленяться, если на "прежде" падает логическое ударение. Тогда запятая ставится внутри союза:
*Ты должна ответить [раньше] прЕжде, чем будет приниматься решение.*
В таких случаях обычно можно подставить "раньше" вместо прежде.
Но: *Ты должна хорошенько подумать раньше, чем решиться.* || Вообще не звучит.

http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=628

Comment: Что  мы здесь уточняем?

Comment: То, от чего ставим вопрос. Но уточнение косвенное.

Comment: Никогда про такое не слышала. Сами придумали? И вопрос неверный. Хотите уточнить время (когда именно),а оно в первой части вообще не называется. Здесь союз дифференцирует по времени отношения между однородными сказуемыми.

Comment: Говорю же, что косвенное - его можно условно так назвать, так как можно задать вопрос. Но оно не дополнительное, а образующее центральный смысл. Вопрос мы задаём примерный, не зная, что будет дальше.

Comment: Пожалуйста, определяя грамматику, используйте грамматическую терминологию. Вы сказали уточнение? Это сужение значения. Пояснение? Это раскрытие значения  местоимения или замена одного слова другим с примерно тем же смыслом. Где у вас всё это?  Я не вижу. У вас есть союз с временным значением, в СПП он используется в придаточных времени. Вот и объясняйте функцию этого союза относительно однородных придаточных. Или это не однородные придаточные? А тогда какие? Вот что хочется услышать от вас, а центральный смысл и всё прочее - это лирика,  сочинительство, не имеющее отношения к анализу.

Comment: Изобилие грамматической терминологии мешает пониманию ответа. Я не использую термин "уточняющие члены предложения", а вы к нему придираетесь.

Comment: Почему же придираюсь. Вы написали: После запятой идёт уточнение. Это термин с определенным значением, но я не вижу здесь уточнения, вот и спросила.  Временной союз определяет последовательность действия, и это всё, но ничего не уточняет из ранее сказанного. Сожалею, что мне не удалось вас в этом убедить.

Comment: Я использую не термин, а обычное русское слово: *Ты должна хорошенько подумать... — Что ты имеешь в виду? Можно поконкретнее? — Ну прежде чем решиться на это.*

Comment: Русская грамматика, изложенная "обычными словами"? Давайте назовем ее "лирическая грамматика".   Но мне лирика нравится только в виде стихов, поэтому спокойной ночи, oleedd (или что у вас там сейчас).

Comment: А вам очень нравится засыпать людей сложными терминами, которые потом нужно гуглить и изучать. Ну-ну... Обычные слова гораздо лучше для объяснений, если вы не защищаете кандидатскую диссертацию.

Comment: Ну всё, дружбе конец, если  вы так считаете. Могу и не засыпать. (По крайней мере суффикс прилагательного  я деривационным аффиксом не называю, как это делают другие). И в своем ответе ни одного сложного термина не вижу, всё очень скромно и понятно. А вот вы даже грамматику не обозначили.  Что у вас соединяет союз: это сложное предложение  или однородные члены?

Comment: "используйте грамматическую терминологию" — вот и прокомментировал это. Да я в общем, не про этот ответ. Объяснять нужно доступно (это я про свои "обычные слова", которые вам не нравятся) - один из принципов педагогики. Даже и не пытаюсь классифицировать предложение (тут спорно), это больше по вашей части. Но такие союзы обычно открывают придаточное.

Comment: Sharon, спасибо, но различить, расчленяется "прежде чем" или нет, действительно, можно только по слуху, в смысловом отношении разница практически отсутствует.

Comment: oleedd, "Ты должна хорошенько подумать прежде" -.здесь прежде не совсем лишнее, ведь можно представить "Ты должна хорошенько подумать прежде" отдельной единицей, если иметь в виду прежде = сначала, передёргивание небольшое))

Comment: Это да, но без него звучит лучше. Смысл в том, чтобы выбрать лучший вариант. Автор имеет право поставить запятую внутри союза, если по его задумке ударение падает на "прежде" (слово подчёркивается голосом), но здесь это не естественно (удаётся подобрать лишь довольно абсурдный контекст). Но хорошо помогает подстановка "раньше".